# Swift 2.0 use of undeclared type UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Why can't i use UIColor in Swift 2.0?

Makes no sense.

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just add `import UIKit` at the top and it will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

You have to import `UIKit` to use `UIColor`.